# Adding Callbacks to GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a mechanism in scikit-learn to add callbacks which execute once every fold has finished training?

Comment: I suppose you can implement a custom Estimator and overwrite appropriate methods to do what you are looking for.

Comment: A hacky way would be to pass you callback as the [`scoring` parameter](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), bur @smishra's suggestion is the cleaner way.